# Datasets with individual rankings

Tags: research

I am looking for real-world dataset examples where there are two types of entities, i.e. students and colleges, and each students has individual ranking for each college (or some of them).

For example are there any datasets for the Stable marriage problem?

Comment: It's not raw data, but check out the hospital / doctor matching problem (PDF) http://www.nrmp.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Main-Match-Results-and-Data-2015_final.pdf